# finding complexity in an if clause

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

assume that I have an if clause

```
if (!f(x))
{
   g(x);
}
```

the complexity of f(x) = O(x^3) and complexity of g(x) = O(x^2).
In this case what is the overall complexity ? O(x^5) ? or O(x^3) ?

I wanted to increase my question sizes.

```
while(z(x))
{
  for(p(x))
  {
     if (!f(x))
     {
       g(x);
     }
  }
}
```

where, z(x) = O(x^5), p(x) = O(x),f(x) = O(x^3), g(x) = O(x^2)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: I believe it must be (x^5)(x)(x^3+x^2).

Comment: You can reduce that further.  When dealing with Big O, if there are added terms, you can simply keep the most expensive one.  And then you can combine all your multiplies.

Comment: I feel suspiciously like I'm doing CS homework here.

Comment: not at all. it is just curiosity of a newbie programmer :)

Answer (score 5):

The total complexity is *O*(*x*<sup>3</sup>) because you have an *x*<sup>3</sup> operation followed (possibly) by an *x*<sup>2</sup> operation. The former dominates the latter: *O*(*x*<sup>3</sup>) + *O*(*x*<sup>2</sup>) = *O*(*x*<sup>3</sup>).

Comment: thanx for the answer. what about if clause has if(f(x) && h(x)){g(x)}, where f(x)=O(x^3) and h(x)=O(x^2) and g(x)=O(x^2).

Comment: @zaratushtra Same result for the same reasons; 3 sequential operations, and the x^3 term dominates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that 'O' complexity exhibit upper bound for that algorithm. Think wrt worst case scenario (upper bound).

In your first case, if your 'if' condition succeed complexity would be O(x3) + O(x2), which will be equivalent to O(x3). since if condition will execute once so you try to add up orders and highest order will define the upper bound.

Now in your second example. Loops will multiply their order with code covered by them. So complexity would be O(x5)*O(x)*(O(x3) + O(X2)). The upper bound of which come out to be O(X8).

Answer (score 0):

For first example it is `O(x^3)` because `O(x^3)` dominates over `O(x^2)` in big-O notation. Second example `O(infinity)` because you dont know when the while loop will end, it may go on for ever so big-O is `O(infinity)` . lower bound for it is O(x^5) because it might get false in first iteration of while